Hold Dt[r,t] unevaluated but Mathematica substitutes value of r
I have the formula for the Volume of the sphere and then differentiate
Dt[V == 4/3 \[Pi] r^3, t]

The output is
Dt[V, t] == 4 \[Pi] r^2 Dt[r, t]

I then want to substitute values for r and Dt[V,t] and leave Dt[r,t] unevaluated so I can solve for it and get the rate at which the sphere's radius grows. I want the Dt[r,t] to remain unchanged but using HoldForm doesn't work.
Dt[V, t] == 4 \[Pi] r^2 HoldForm[Dt[r, t]] /. {Dt[V, t] -> 10, r -> 4}

The output is
10==64*Pi*Dt[4,t]

What I want the output to be is
10==64*Pi*Dt[r,t]

Is there a way to keep Dt[r,t] and not Mathematica substitute 4 for r?

I usually do this sort of thing (keep a form from having substitutions applied) as follows:
Dt[V == 4/3 \[Pi] r^3, t] /.
  {d : Dt[r, t] :> d, Dt[V, t] -> 10, r -> 4}

(*  10 == 64 \[Pi] Dt[r, t]  *)

Since ReplaceAll works from the top down (breadth first) and applies the first matching rule to a part; the replacement expression is inserted and no rules are applied to it. Consequently, the no-op rule d : Dt[r, t] :> d will be applied to a matching part (in this case, literally Dt[r, t]), but none of the other rules in the list will be applied to it.

If you want to solve for Dt[r, t], then just solve for it:
Solve[Dt[V, t] == 4 \[Pi] r^2 Dt[r, t], Dt[r, t]]
(* {{Dt[r, t] -> Dt[V, t]/(4*Pi*r^2)}} *)

Or
SolveValues[Dt[V, t] == 4 \[Pi] r^2 Dt[r, t], Dt[r, t]]
(* {Dt[V, t]/(4*Pi*r^2)} *)

Now you can do your substitutions.
As for the HoldForm behavior... HoldForm doesn't make what it wraps invisible, it just keeps it from being evaluated. In this case, it wasn't necessary, because you can already see that Dt[r, t] didn't evaluate any further, so wrapping it with HoldForm won't do anything. But the entire HoldForm[Dt[r, t]] expression is still just an expression, so ReplaceAll will still "see" inside of it and be able to do replacements.
